# Using multiple Python functions within AWS Lambda script

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

**SITUATION**

I'm using a Lambda function that takes a CSV attachment from an incoming email and places it into what is, in effect, a sub-folder of an S3 bucket. This part of the Lambda works well, however there are other UDFs which I need to execute, within the same Lambda function, to perform susequent tasks.

**CODE**

```
    import boto3 
    
    import email
    import base64
    
    import math
    import pickle
    
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    
    import io 
    
    
    ###############################
    ###    GET THE ATTACHMENT   ###
    ###############################
    
    #s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    
    
    FILE_MIMETYPE = 'text/csv'
    #'application/octet-stream'
    
    # destination folder
    S3_OUTPUT_BUCKETNAME = 'my_bucket' 
    
    print('Loading function')
    
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    
    
    def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
        #source email bucket 
        inBucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
        key = urllib.parse.quote(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'].encode('utf8'))
    
    
        try:
            response = s3.get_object(Bucket=inBucket, Key=key)
            msg = email.message_from_string(response['Body'].read().decode('utf-8'))   
    
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            print('Error retrieving object {} from source bucket {}. Verify existence and ensure bucket is in same region as function.'.format(key, inBucket))
            raise e
        
    
        attachment_list = []
       
    
        try:
            #scan each part of email 
            for message in msg.walk():
                
                # Check filename and email MIME type
                if  (message.get_content_type() == FILE_MIMETYPE and message.get_filename() != None):
                    attachment_list.append ({'original_msg_key':key, 'attachment_filename':message.get_filename(), 'body': base64.b64decode(message.get_payload()) })
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            print ('Error processing email for CSV attachments')
            raise e
        
        # if multiple attachments send all to bucket 
        for attachment in attachment_list:
    
            try:
                s3.put_object(Bucket=S3_OUTPUT_BUCKETNAME, Key='attachments/' + attachment['original_msg_key'] + '-' + attachment['attachment_filename'] , Body=attachment['body']
            )
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                print ('Error sending object {} to destination bucket {}. Verify existence and ensure bucket is in same region as function.'.format(attachment['attachment_filename'], S3_OUTPUT_BUCKETNAME))
                raise e

#################################
###    ADDITIONAL FUNCTIONS   ###
#################################
    
    def my_function():
      print("Hello, this is another function")
```

**OUTCOME**

The CSV attachment is successfully retrieved and placed in the destination as specified by s3.put_object, however there is no evidence in the Cloudwatch logs that my_function runs.

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED**

I've tried using def my_function(event, context): in an attempt to ascertain whether the function requires the same criteria to be executed as the first functon. I've also tried to include the my_function() as part of the first function but this does not appear to work either.

How can I ensure that both functions are executed within the Lambda?

Comment: You are not invoking your `my_function` at all. Just invoke it  in your  `lambda_handler` at the end of the handler.

Comment: The Lambda service invokes the Python function that *you* configured when you created/updated the Lambda function. It doesn't magically call 'all functions with a given argument signature'.

Comment: @Marcin What do you mean when you say 'invoke it in your `lambda_handler` at the end of the handler'

Comment: I mean add `my_function()` in your `lambda_handler` where you want to invoke your function.

Comment: Write code inside your `lambda_handler(...)` function that calls `my_function()`. Just like you would do in regular Python.

Comment: Got it, thanks @Jarmod and @Marcin.
I have defined my fucntion outside of the `lambda_handler` as `def my_function():
      print("Hello, this is another function")` and then simply called `my_function` from within the `lambda_handler`, based on placing the call in the desired location and at the right indentation level.

Comment: I can confirm that the function has been executed due to the presence of the function output in the Cloudwatch logs

Comment: Great, so it's all resolved? If so, you might want to ask @Marcin to write up an answer because he gave the first correct response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was caused because `my_function` function **was not called** inside the lambda handler.

The **solution** was to add `my_function()` into the handler `lambda_handler` so that the `my_function` is actually called.